# My data at a certain latitude is disappearing in Mapbox Studio?

Tags: mapbox, grids-graticules, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

I'm trying to make a simple map showing 4 villages in Alaska (and Fairbanks for reference) but for some reason the northernmost village is being cut-off it seems. When viewing the data in Mapbox Studio there is a mysterious line that seems to be the culprit? I have no idea what this line is from. See picture below.

The coordinates for the disappearing village are -152.65091, 66.56305. Here is the data file in geojson format as a gist [villages.geojson gist](https://gist.github.com/joshuahouston/0f7d9cef35812897dacc)[image: data cut off by mysterious line]

And here is the working map [Map](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/jfactory/cilnbt887003v9gkfz3wkyljt.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiamZhY3RvcnkiLCJhIjoiZXdJam1yZyJ9.-AOTWD0gk1_3wuciI3DbsQ#4.46/65.529/-151.880)

Comment: It appears that the town is drawn, but the graticule is drawn over the top, so perhaps you can look to see if you can change the order of drawing, or the default spacing of the graticule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that is clipping your type is a tile boundary. The clipping can occur in certain cases where data/labeling exists at the edge of a tile boundary. You can "debug" your map and adjust labeling and such to avoid these artifacts using the setting shown below.

[image: Tile boundaries]